# unable to read large csv file from s3 bucket to python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3

So I am trying to load a csv file from s3 bucket. The following is the code

```py
import pandas as pd
import boto3
import io

s3_file_key = 'iris.csv'
bucket = 'data'

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=s3_file_key)

initial_df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))
```

It works fine. iris.csv is only 3kb in size.
Now instead of iris.csv, I try to read 'mydata.csv' which is 6gb in size.

I get the following error :

> ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied

I am unable to comprehend how access can be an issue since I put the data there in the first place. Also I am able to read 'iris.csv' from the same location. Any ideas?

Comment: Check permissions and whether `mydata.csv` is maybe encrypter with a KMS key or similar. The fact that you've uploaded the file in first place and that you can read another file isn't really relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the few things that you can do:

1. Make sure the region of the S3 bucket is the same as your AWS configure. Otherwise, it won't work. S3 service is global but every bucket is created in a specific region. The same region should be used by AWS clients.
2. Make sure the access keys for the resource has the right set of permissions.
3. Make sure the file is actually uploaded.
4. Make sure there is no bucket policy applied that revokes access.
5. You can enable logging on your S3 bucket to see errors.
6. Make sure the bucket is not versioned. If versioned, specify the object version.
7. Make sure the object has the correct set of ACLs defined.
8. If the object is encrypted, make sure you have permission to use that KMS key to decrypt the object.