# Fastest option for reading the data for pandas from S3 bucket?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having a dataset of around 400 mb in CSV, In my local i tried several data formats to achieve the fastest reading time. The parquet format partitioned on date turned out to be the best fit.
But when i shifted to S3 bucket, it took so long to read same file using aws data wrangler.

Being new to AWS world i need to know what should be the best method to achieve the fastest running time.
Given :

I have date as one of feature and I can use it to partitioning. Also I need it as a pandas **dataframe** after reading it .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773477/unable-to-read-large-csv-file-from-s3-bucket-to-python   Check this out

Comment: Where is your code running? On your own computer, or on something in AWS? If it is in AWS, is it in the same region as the Amazon S3 bucket?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes they are in same region.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i am running my code on aws

Comment: Did you get your answer? I am also looking for fastest way to read/write data in S3 with pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked different file formats' read and write times and how much space they take in S3. I uploaded one CSV file in the bucket. Ran the code in AWS lambda to read that CSV in Pandas and write/read to different formats in the same bucket. Here are the results:

| Format | Read | Write | Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CSV | 0.8764 s | 1.7581 s | 5.9985 MB |
| JSON | 2.5027 s | 0.9272 s | 12.0038 MB |
| Parquet | 0.4262 s | 0.5380 s | **1.1713 MB** |
| Feather | **0.2255 s** | **0.2664 s** | 7.5699 MB |

Feather seems to be the fastest, but it increases the size a bit compared to CSV (because it uses uncompressed format). For CSV, JSON, and feather, I have used AWSWrangler, and for feather used pyarrow's `write_feather`. Here is the Python script: [pandas_s3_comparison](https://gist.github.com/mr-easy/8522fe2aee9040392fd284289caedbcf)

Answer (score 1):

There is a format called feather, it might help you out.

More details here - [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-best-format-to-save-pandas-data-414dca023e0d)

[image]

Comment: thanks for sharing but in my case i want to read it from S3 bucket.